# Finding the derivative of $x$ in $Ax=b$ with the inverse/implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, implicit-function-theorem

Let's say I have a regular matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, with ($b$ and $x$ are also in $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$)
$$Ax=b$$

I want to find the derivative of the solution $x$ to this system of linear equations, by the entries of the matrix and the entries of $b$, so I am looking for $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial a_{ij}},\frac{\partial x}{\partial b_i}$$

I do not quite understand how to solve this problem. I am familiar with the implicit function theorem and with the inverse function theorem and I am pretty sure that these will come in handy. I tried applying the inverse function theorem, but I end up with the inverse of a vector, which cannot be quite right. What is the best way to start here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ is assumed to be regular, you can write
$$x= A^{-1}b$$
Differentiating this with respect to $b$ (or $b_i$) is trivial, since it's linear.
Differentiating the inverse of $A$ is slightly more complex, but if you note that $A^{-1} A = I$ it's quite obvious how to approach this. The result is more than well documented, so I'll just give you [this link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf), where you will find it on page 8.

Comment: The link is broken